# The constructor for HSMWalletMixin in HLF 1.4 doesn't have the correct variables

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hsm

I'm trying to connect to an HSM using fabric-network V1.4.17 looking at the HSMWalletMixin constructor there are no options to tell the class the library label and pin.

Instead all these variables can be found in the X509WalletMixin.

Here's the code in the class:

```
export interface WalletMixin {} // tslint:disable-line:no-empty-interface

export class X509WalletMixin implements WalletMixin {
    public static createIdentity(mspId: string, certificate: string, privateKey: string): Identity;
    constructor(library?: string, slot?: string, pin?: string, userType?: string);
}

export class HSMWalletMixin implements WalletMixin {
    public static createIdentity(mspId: string, certificate: string): Identity;
    constructor();
}
```

So I tried creating an HSM Wallet using the X509WalletMixin like below, but it created a regular wallet instead.

```
const hsmWalletMixin = new X509WalletMixin('/path/to/lib/libCryptoki2_64.so', 'slot', 'pin');
const wallet = new FileSystemWallet(walletPath, hsmWalletMixin);
```

So, How can create an HSM Wallet then? are there some environment variables like in this tutorial [Testing for Hardware Security Module via PKCS#11](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/tutorial-hsm-pkcs11.html)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code the implementation is correct
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/4ca22aa1a70f464c3a5b9c259542aa7fee651061/fabric-network/lib/impl/wallet/hsmwalletmixin.js#L40

What is not correct are the type definitions which is the code snippet you have posted.

It's only going to be an issue if you are using typescript in which case you will just have to not use the HSMWalletMixin type to ensure typescript doesn't try to do any validation.

Comment: actually still doesn't work but I found that using environment variables CRYPTO_PKCS11_LIB, CRYPTO_PKCS11_SLOT, CRYPTO_PKCS11_PIN does the trick. thanks

Comment: Strange that it doesn't work because I use it via the constructor.

`
      const hsmOptions = config.getHsmOptions();
      const mixin = new HsmWalletMixin(hsmOptions.lib, hsmOptions.slot, hsmOptions.pin);
      this.hsmWallet = new InMemoryWallet(mixin);
`

Are you using typescript ? in which case you need to stop typescript from trying to validate the constructor

Comment: no, I'm using js, I get an alert saying that the PKCS11_LIB can not be null, I'm using it like this: const hsmWalletMixin = new HSMWalletMixin(
            myLib, mySlot, myKey); const wallet = new FileSystemWallet(walletPath, hsmWalletMixin); but using the variables worked. Although I had an error, I was using the partition label instead of the slot so that may be the reason it failed but the error wasn't clear, I need to try again, also I placed a Jira in hyperledger for the ts types, I hope they fix it. Tks